# Bind Shared Library Reference with application

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to install the EAR on WAS 8.5 ND with the Ant target "wsInstallApp". I have created a shared library reference which I want to add to the application. How can I add it through Ant Script to automate my deployment process or is there any other way through which application binds to this shared library reference e.g deployment descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `wsadmin` and `python/jacl` script. From an ant script perspective you can create a task to call `wsadmin`. Use the following documentation link to create administrative script. [Shared library docs.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_applibrary.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me and it binds the Shared Reference Liberary to the installed application.

Comment: Hi Tiwari, Can u please help me by sharing your code ? i am trying to do the same... it is eluding me..

Comment: @VijayAthreyan you can find out the details from here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/706a5f30-025f-4dc3-b162-01e918fe489e/entry/Application_Edition_Management_and_Automatic_Deployment_with_Ant_Script?lang=en